# Java Imgproc's OpenCV's GC_INIT_WITH_MASK giving odd results

Tags: java, android, opencv, mask, image-segmentation

On first segmentation, I did it with GC_INIT_WITH_RECT and it is working fine. But on second segmentation I used GC_INIT_WITH_MASK but it is giving me weird results.

A new mask `newmask` is created and it is filled with GC_PR_BGD, which is probably background.

```
    newmask = new Mat(bitmapImage.getHeight(), bitmapImage.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(Imgproc.GC_PR_BGD));
```

I have a canvas where I could draw on the mask with an image as a visual reference. And I have a button to change `gcColor` into GC_PR_FGD, GC_FGD, GC_BGD. With this, I could mark the probably foreground, sure foreground, and sure background of the image.

```
if (count == 0) {
        paintDraw.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        gcColor = new Scalar(Imgproc.GC_PR_FGD);
    } else if (count == 1) {
        paintDraw.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        gcColor = new Scalar(Imgproc.GC_FGD);
    } else if (count == 2) {
        paintDraw.setColor(Color.RED);
        gcColor = new Scalar(Imgproc.GC_BGD);
    }
```

Drawing on the `newmask`:

```
Imgproc.circle(newmask, nm, 10, gcColor, 10); //nm being the Point
```

Code for grabcut with mask:

```
    Bitmap bmp = bitmapImage;

    Mat img = new Mat();
    Bitmap bmp32 = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp32, img);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img, img, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2BGR);

    // Up to this point: Bitmap is converted to Mat and removes alpha channel

    Mat background = new Mat(img.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    Mat bgModel = new Mat();
    Mat fgModel = new Mat();

    Mat source = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(Imgproc.GC_PR_FGD));
    Mat dst = new Mat();

    Rect rect = new Rect(tl, br); // rect coordinates from previous segmentation

    Imgproc.grabCut(img, newmask, rect, bgModel, fgModel, 1, Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK);

    Core.compare(newmask, source, newmask, Core.CMP_EQ);

    Mat segmentedImg= new Mat(img.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    img.copyTo(segmentedImg, newmask); //segmented image stored in segmentedImg as a Mat
```

As I understand it, everything outside the `rect` is labelled as background. But when I get back the segmented image, the areas outside of the `rect` were also affected by the GC_INIT_WITH_MASK.

[First grabcut with rect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gum1g.jpg)

[Result of grabcut with mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WzCD.jpg)

*red marking is GC_BGD which is sure background

*blue marking is GC_FGD which is sure foreground